# react redux props undefined on event listener when using mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

My first time using react/redux and I'm trying to bind a simple action `addClick` to the 'click' event, but when I click I receive the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

My (stripped down) code is:

```js
import {addClick} from './actions'
const mapDispatchToProps = {addClick}
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.props.addClick)
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.props.addClick)
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Before I had it implemented without `mapDispatchToProps` using an action creator defined within the class and bound to `this` in the constructor. But I thought part of the point of `mapDispatchToProps` was to bind the action creator to `this` (as well as wrapping it in a `dispatch`)

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the code to your action creator `addClick`?  Are you using "this" inside on the addClick?

Comment: Wow, I'm so dumb! I was using `this.props` inside the action from before when I had defined it and bound it within the class.

Comment: Hehe, it happens to the best (and will happen again)  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use props inside `addClick` action?

Check this example:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { connect, Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";

function addClick(event) {
  return {
    type: "CLICK",
    payload: `pageX: ${event.pageX} | pageY: ${event.pageY}`
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    clickXY: state
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = { addClick };

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.props.addClick);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.props.addClick);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>
        Click message: {this.props.clickXY}
      </h1>
    );
  }
}

function clickReducer(state = "None", action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CLICK": {
      return action.payload;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

let store = createStore(clickReducer);

const AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

render(<Root />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Link to [editor](https://codesandbox.io/s/08pvzp18v)

So bind works well in this code.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell from the documentation, the object short-hand (`const mapDispatchToProps =
 {addClick}`) you use for `mapDispatchToProps` doesn't bind `this` to anything. It just sees to it that your `addClick` action creator gets called with dispatch. So that if you, in your component execute `addClick(3)`, then that will result in a call looking like this `dispatch(addClick(3))`.

I'm not sure why your action creator would need access to `this` though. Can't you just pass it what ever data it needs as a parameter? So that the call in your component might look like

```js
componentDidMount() {
        const {addClick, someOtherProp} = this.props;
        document.addEventListener('click', () => addClick(someOtherProp));
    }
```